# semantic-release is configured to only publish from master

Tags: node.js, git, devops, semantic-release

> [16:07:15] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Running semantic-release version 17.0.4
>   [16:07:18] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/npm"
>   [16:07:19] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/git"
>   [16:07:19] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "analyzeCommits" from "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
>   [16:07:19] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "generateNotes" from "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
>   [16:07:19] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "prepare" from "@semantic-release/changelog"
>   [16:07:19] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "prepare" from "@semantic-release/npm"
>   [16:07:19] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "prepare" from "@semantic-release/git"
>   [16:07:19] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "publish" from "@semantic-release/npm"
>   [16:07:20] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "publish" from "@semantic-release/gitlab"
>   [16:07:20] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "addChannel" from "@semantic-release/npm"
>   [16:07:20] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "addChannel" from "@semantic-release/github"
>   [16:07:27] [semantic-release] › ℹ  This test run was triggered on the branch development, while semantic-release is configured to only publish from master, therefore a new version won’t be published.

On .releaserc.js

```
module.exports = {
  branch: 'development',
```

Comment: You forgot to write/ask a question.

Answer (score 6):

The correct option is `branches`. See https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#branches